# replacing a column value with a constant in codeigniter select query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, select

I have a query in codeigniter like this `$this->db->select('t.*,m.last_traded_price online_curr_nav, m.actual_change days_change')`
now in place of `m.actual_change`, i have to pass a constant say "NA" to days_change. PLease tell how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want this:

```
$this->db->select('t.*,m.last_traded_price online_curr_nav, 
m.actual_change days_change, "NA" as days_change')
```